# How to prolong the waiting period of a windows service shutting down?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Using RequestAdditionalTime for a windows service, does not prolong the waiting period long enough.
I have to wait for a job to finish , so i keep on

```
            while (gs_bisProcessing)
            {
                OnRequestMoreTime(20000);
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
            }
```

but still the job takes long enough that the service while stopping, gives the message box that the service did not respond in a timely fashion... and teh state of the service stays 'Stopping' even if you refresh.
So what to do now?
I want to do the same thing onShutdown too? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean RequestAdditionalTime(ms)?

I'd probably check prior to 20 seconds elapsing, that seems to be about the magic number.  I wouldn't sleep that long, but probably be checking your flag every 10-15 seconds instead.

Comment: Calling `RequestAdditionalTime` within the `OnShutdown` handler will cause an `InvalidOperationException`